# FTP: Removing an entire directory

Tags: ftp, download

Is there any way to delete a non-empty directory in Linux using FTP?
I am using client, and I wish to delete the directory in a remote server.

I have looked into `wget` and `curl`. What do you guys think?

Comment: A couple ways are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749517/ftp-delete-non-empty-directory